# How do I use the Adafruit-Blinka Python library as a normal (non-root) user?

Tags: python, raspberrypi

I'm running Python 3.8.2 on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS running on a Raspberry Pi 3b+. I've installed python3-pip as well as python-is-python3. I am not currently using venv because this will be the only application on the RPi.

I'd like to use the Adafruit-Blinka library in Python programs on the RPi. I've installed it as root:

sudo pip3 install --upgrade Adafruit-Blinka

Here is my test program:

```
import board
import digitalio
import busio

print("Hello blinka!")

# Try to get a Digital input
pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D4)
print("Digital IO ok!")

# Try to create an I2C device
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
print("I2C ok!")

# Try to create an SPI device
spi = busio.SPI(board.SCLK, board.MOSI, board.MISO)
print("SPI ok!")

print("done!")
```

Running it as root works fine:

```
sudo python blinkatest.py
```

Produces:

```
sbn@ubuntu:~$ sudo python blinkatest.py
Hello blinka!
Digital IO ok!
I2C ok!
SPI ok!
done!
sbn@ubuntu:~$
```

Running as non-root produces:

```
sbn@ubuntu:~$ python blinkatest.py
Hello blinka!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blinkatest.py", line 8, in <module>
    pin = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D4)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/digitalio.py", line 106, in __init__
    self.direction = Direction.INPUT
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/digitalio.py", line 136, in direction
    self._pin.init(mode=Pin.IN)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/bcm283x/pin.py", line 37, in init
    GPIO.setup(self.id, GPIO.IN)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
sbn@ubuntu:~$
```

So, is there a way to run a Python program on Ubuntu Server on RPi that accesses the hardware without running it as root? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Do `ls  -ld /dev/mem`. If it allows group access (`man -a chmod`), do `sudo adduser $USER $(stat -G /dev/mem)`. Then logout/ login

Comment: /dev/mem permissions were rw-r--r-- so I added group write (`chmod g+w /dev/mem`) and then added my user to the kmem group (the group for /dev/mem) but still no joy. I'll try it again tomorrow - I certainly may have missed something. Thanks for the suggestion.